# Can every algorithm's running time be expressed as $\Theta(f(n))$?

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity

That is, can the running time of every algorithm $A$ be written as $O(f_A(n))$ and $\Omega(f_A(n))$, for the same function $f_A$?

Comment: It wasn't clear from the original wording (before I edited it) whether "running time" actually means "*worst-case* running time".

Comment: For all $f$, $f \in \Theta(f)$. I think there is some (sub)text waiting to be made explicit here.

Comment: I suspect the original poster intended $f_A$ to be a _simple_ function.

Answer (score 12):

The best case running time and the worst case running time on inputs of length $n$ can each be expressed in this way (as can any function of $n$), however, the two measures do not need to coincide. Details follow.

The running time of an algorithm is not a function only of input size $n$ but a function of the input and there are various running time measure that you can define as functions of $n$. You can define $f_A(n)$ as the worst case (=largest) running time over inputs of size $n$ and $g_A(n)$ as the best case (=smallest) running time over inputs of size $n$. Alex's argument is basically that $f_A(n) = \Theta(g_A(n))$ is not true for every algorithm $A$. The big-oh, big-omega and big-theta notations are used to denote the growth rate of a function as its argument goes to infinity - **by itself $\Omega()$ doesn't say whether you are talking about worst case running time or best case running time, and neither does $O()$**. So for the insertion sort you have:

- $f_A(n) = \Theta(n^2)$ because you never need more than $O(n^2)$ steps to finish sorting and for each $n$ there is an input (reverse order) for which the algorithm takes at least $C n^2$ time for some constant $C$.
- $g_A(n) = \Theta(n)$ because for each $n$ there is an input (sorted array) for which insertion sort runs in linear time and of course you need at least linear time to read the array.

And of course $f_A(n) = \Theta(f_A(n))$ and $g_A(n) = \Theta(g_A(n))$. However, $f_A$ and $g_A$ need not be monotonically increasing, they can oscillate infinitely often.

If you feel comfortable with all that you might check this discussion too: http://blog.computationalcomplexity.org/2005/01/big-omega.html

Comment: I think you could add just a short answer at the beginning to become a really great answer.

Comment: @AlexGrilo thanks for the suggestion, fixed now

Comment: Doesn't "running time" mean "worst-case running time" by default?

Comment: I only wrote this because there was some confusion with the other two answers

Comment: @JeffE: Depends on who's talking, I guess. Most definitions I know define runtime $T(x)$ and then worst-case runtime $T(n) = \max \{ T(x) \mid |x|=n\}$. Afterwards, the distinction is typically dropped because most people in (the complexity-theory-part of) mostly talk about worst-case.

Answer (score 4):

To show that Sasho's answer doesn't just hold for pathological algorithms, here's an example.

Consider a factorization algorithm that (1) tests whether a number $N$ is prime, (2) checks whether $N$ is divisible by small primes, (3) uses a factorization algorithm that is superpolynomial (such as all known ones).

In the cases where $N$ is prime or $N$ only has small prime factors, the algorithm runs in polynomial time in the input size $\log N$. For the hardest numbers to factor, the best known algorithm runs in time $2^{\Omega(\log^{1/3} N)}$, much slower.

Answer (score 2):

No. For some inputs an algorithm can run faster or slower.

For instance, insertion sort can run in $O(n)$ time when the input array is already sorted but it requires $\Omega(n^2)$ time for arrays in reversed order.

Comment: Alex, I don't think that answers the question. Can't big-theta just be of n^2 then? There is a big theta represention for every algorithm.

Comment: A Theta representation for every algorithm means that the running time for *every* input must be within that function class. As I showed in my example, there is an algorithm for which this is not true.

Comment: This is ambigious as to whether you are talking about worst case, average case, best case... etc. Big-O and Big-Theta are just was of classifying functions. Their definitions themselves don't actually say anything about which function you're analyzing, whether it be best or worst or average case running time.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  If your alphabet $\Sigma$ is finite then the number of words of length $n$ is finite for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

This means that if you have an algorithm A, you can define $f_A$ as being $f_A(n) = \max_{w}t(A(w))$ where the $\max$ is taken over all strings of length $n$ and $t(A(w))$ is the time measure of $A$ run on input $w$.  The worst case complexity of $A$ is then $\Theta(f_A)$.

You can define it similarly for average and best case by taking respectively average and minimum of all time measures.

Answer (score 1):

As a simple proof-by-contradiction take a look at any algorithm who's complexity depends on more than one variable, e.g.: $\mathcal{O}(nk)$.

In such a case it is rarely possible to express running time as $\mathcal{O}\big( f(n) \big)$.

Comment: I'm sure OP assumes the number of variables is equal to the arity of the function.  But otherwise you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following problem:

1. Input: a list $l$ of integers of length $n$ and an integer $m$.
2. Output: a list $l'$ containing the elements of $l$ in ascending sorted order if $n$ is even, or a Boolean value indicating whether $m$ is contained in $l$ if $n$ is odd.

Consider the following algorithm:

```
if n % 2 = 0 return sort(l)
else if n % 2 = 1 return search(l, m)
```

The best-case behavior of this is that $n$ is odd, in which case the lower bound is $\Omega(n)$ (assuming linear search); the worst-case behavior is when $n$ is odd, in which case the upper bound is $O(n \log n)$. So the "universal" case of this algorithm does not have a $\Theta$ bound.

Note that the best and worst cases of this algorithm do have $\Theta$ bounds. Bounds apply to cases, not to algorithms (when we apply bounds to algorithms directly, a case is usually understood; often we mean the worst case, but sometimes - as in this example - we mean a sort of "universal" case considering all inputs without weighting).